# Does a continuous random variable generate a partition?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space, and $X(\omega)$ a discrete r.v.

$X$ generates the partition $\mathcal{D}_X=\{D_1,D_2,\cdots,D_n,\cdots\}$, where $D_i=\{\omega:X(\omega)=x_i\}, i=1,2,\cdots,n,\cdots$.

Let $Y(\omega)$ be a continuous r.v.

My question is: does $Y$ generate a partition too? I think that in the continuous case this would imply an uncountable union of sets, which would be against the definition of $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Use $n\lt Y_n\le n+1$ to define partition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. The general principle behind your idea is: If $P=\{P_i\}$ is a partition of the image of $X$ (or a partition of some superset of the image), then $\{ X\in P_i\}$ is a partition of $\omega$. This is easy to see: If $P_i\cap P_j=\emptyset$ then $X^{-1}(P_i)\cap X^{-1}(P_j)=\emptyset$, and for each $\omega\in\Omega$ there is some $P_i$ so that $X(\omega)\in P_i$, so $\omega$ in $X^{-1}(P_i)$.

So for example if you take $\mathcal D_X = \{ D_i \}$ where $D_i = \{ X \in (i, i+1]\}$ this gives you an at most countable partition of $\Omega$.

Of course you can also define the partition $\{ D_x \}$ with $D_x = \{ X=x\}$. Unless $X$ is constant this then gives you an uncountable partition. But this has nothing to do with the $\sigma$-Algebra.